# Plugin Window with .Show() disables DataGrid Ctrl+C function .ShowDialog() doesn't

Tags: c#, wpf, revit-api

I'm working on a plugin dll for Revit. If I render the main window with .Show() the DataGrid lose it's function to be copied by pressing Ctrl+C. However if I use .ShowDialog() Ctrl+C works fine. I do not want the window to be modal and want to use .Show() method.

Do you have any idea how to correct Ctrl+C function with .Show() method?
Thanks

Comment: show a modeless dialog on single-thread applications (like Revit) can be unsafe... be careful

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the key is to make your form a child of the Revit process.

See Jeremy's blog post here:
http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/02/revit-window-handle-and-modeless-dialogues.html